# How to update a sub-object in a MongoDB collection with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to both Spring Data and StackOverflow.

To make it simple, in my database I have a 'user' collection in which I have a user document with a 'myApp' subobject and a 'param' subobject.

Currently I'm able to upsert 'param' in my user document except that what I want to do is to upsert to 'param' in 'myApp'.

What is the good practice please?

Here is my current request:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> setParam(String key, Param param){
        Query q = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(Auth.getUserId(key)));
        q.fields().include("myApp");
        Update u = Update.update("param", param).set("param", param);
        mongoTemplate.findAndModify(q, u, new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true).upsert(false), User.class);
        return null;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried a lot of stuff and I finally found the solution!

It was enough in the .update to do "myApp.param" and in the .set to do "myApp.param" !

Hoping that it could be useful for others.